# Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl is not getting tied to managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint, taxonomy

I have a requirement to show a taxonomyfield on a publishing page, already the page is created with a publishing page layout [created with a publishing content type, with metadata columns], A content field which is added as The TaxonomyFieldControl is being shown when the page is in edit mode only, but I need to show the taxonomy field on the normal mode of the page, so I have added a content field as TaxonomyWebTaggingControl, to be shown normally on any page mode. But, the problem is for TaxonomyFieldContorl, the metadata is getting tied up and shows the respective term set, but for the TaxonomyWebTaggingControl no term set is getting bound to the control.

Here are the field declarations.

**Working declarations**

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="c6027859-c15e-464f-8485-c7f0aa6f1219" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl> 
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="Product" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl>
```

**Not working declarations**

```
 <Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl FieldName="c6027859-c15e-464f-8485-c7f0aa6f1219"  runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>

<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl FieldName="Product" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl
```

Here the `FieldName` is a metadata field.

Comment: Have you tried putting the guid between brackets? 
{c6027859-c15e-464f-8485-c7f0aa6f1219}

Answer (score 1):

For [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.aspx) control two properties are mandatory to bind this control with Managed Metadata Service (MMS):

[TermStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termstore.aspx)

[TermSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termset.aspx)

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl 
FieldName="Product" 
SSPList="Id of TermStore" 
TermSetList="Id of TermSet" 
runat="server">
</Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>
```

Below is demonstrated how to initialize it programmatically:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializing TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control
/// </summary>
/// <param name="countryControl"> </param>
/// <param name="session"></param>
/// <param name="countriesTermSet"></param>
private void InitCountriesControl(TaxonomyWebTaggingControl countryControl, TaxonomySession session, TermSet countriesTermSet)
{
        countryControl.SSPList = countriesTermSet.TermStore.Id.ToString();
        countryControl.TermSetList = countriesTermSet.Id.ToString();
 }
```

For more details please follow post [Using SharePoint TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control: specifying parent terms](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/01/21/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-specifying-parent-terms/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. I always set the information of the TaxonomyFieldWebTaggingControl by code.

In the code below, this information is hard-coded.

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(SPContext.Current.Site);
TermStore store = taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
Group group = store.Groups["Your Term Group Name"];

tfwtControl.SspId.Add(store.Id);
tfwtControl.SSPList = store.Id.ToString();
tfwtControl.TermSetId.Add(group.TermSets["Your Termset Name"].Id);
tfwtControl.TermSetList = group.TermSets["Your Termset Name"].Id.ToString();
```